# How do I setup Memcached with Pressflow/Drupal?

Tags: drupal, memcached, pressflow

With Pressflow 6.20 (port of Drupal), my aim is to setup memcache. I am having cache consistency issues:

1. Menu showing wrong inactive tabs.
2. Passing a variable at the end of the url `?val=test` is useless.

Comment: You don't need pressflow just for memcached. Memcached runs fine on a vanilla Drupal. I am quite certain that your problems are not caused by memcached, but by a misconfigured pressflow.

Comment: This might be good to know. The caching with memcache and pressflow didn't work properly for a site that I set up. After debugging I found that the page_cache_lifetime var is never set with the consequence that the value of CACHE_TEMPORARY is used. I found this bug report that states that using memcached isn't a best practice, so that won't be considered as a critical bug and hence not fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pressflow/+bug/575754

Answer (score 0):

Don NOT use memcached with Pressflow. It is absolutely unnecessary and hassle. I've seen a lot of performace boost after after I saw andrew's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957684/how-to-set-up-memcache-on-nginxfastcgi/9731132#9731132) and  disabled memcached on Pressflow.  John P's comment above seems to refer to the same (set of) problems.